# Javascript - Помогите исправить код

Tags: javascript, html

Пожалуйста помогите исправить код.

1. Вместо числа пишет NaN
2. Хочу что бы отображались не только минуты
3. Как отключить обновление кода каждую секунду

```js
var time = document.getElementById('er').value; //поле ввода
var sktm = document.getElementById('sktm');     //поле вывода
var bur = document.getElementById("og");        //поле кнопки
bur.addEventListener('click', function()
 {
  time = parseInt(time.value) * 60;
  return time;
});
bur = setInterval(function () {
   var seconds = time % 60; // Получаем секунды
   var minutes = time  ;// Получаем минуты
   var hour = time * 60  ;// Получаем часы
    // Условие если время закончилось то...
    if (time <= 0) {
        // Выводит сообщение что время закончилось
        alert("Время закончилось");
    } else { // Иначе
        // Создаём строку с выводом времени
        var jj = minutes;
        // Выводим строку в блок для показа таймера
        sktm.innerHTML = minutes ;
    }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="author" content="Конюхов Никита">
    <meta name="description" content="Тест строница">
    <meta  name=" keyword"
    content="текст проверка ">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

    
 </head>
 <body>
<div id="go">Боссы</div>
<div id="rat">Скелет</div>
<div><input type="text" placeholder="Введите минуты до босса" id="er" ></div>
<div id="og" ><button type="button" value="Готово">Готово</button></div>
<div id="sktm"></div>
<script src="java/main.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1)Добавьте проверку число ли это:

```js
var seconds = (isNumeric(time) ? time : 1) % 60;
var minutes = (isNumeric(time) ? time : 1);
var hour = (isNumeric(time) ? time : 1) * 60;
```

Дополнительно, советую заменить тип input на number:

```html
<input type="number" placeholder="Введите минуты до босса" id="er">
```

2)Как вариант:

```js
sktm.innerHTML = seconds + " секунд " + minutes + " минут " + hour + "часов";
```

3)setInterval принимает два аргумента: function и число (частоту обновления в миллисекундах)

```js
bur = setInterval(function () {
   // Код
}, 1000 /* - так что вам надо менять его (1000 миллисекунд = 1 секунда) */);
```